# Starting daemons as www-data

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

Is there a good was to start daemons as normal user?

I would like to place a little script on my homeserver to start und stop services like proftpd, mysql and samba. I tried it like this, but had no luck.

sudo -u root -S /etc/init.d/proftpd start < /home/name/password

Comment: See the great answers below, but note that you shouldn't be starting a bunch of daemons under the same user: The goal here is to minimize the access someone gets if they compromise a daemon, so Apache, MySQL, Samba, etc. should be getting their own service users.

Comment: Which of these do you want to do?
1) Change the user and group id that the daemon is running as?
2) Provide a way for a user who normally would not have the permission to start the daemon to start it noninteractively?
Your question title makes me think #1, but your question text makes me think #2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to give the `www-data` user the ability to start and stop certain daemons, but that you don't want to change the user that the daemons run as. You can do this easily with [sudo](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/intro.html). First, run `visudo` to safely edit `/etc/sudoers`. Now, define a command alias that lists all the init scripts for the daemons you want the `www-data` user to be able to control. The name of the alias is arbitrary. I don't know the exact names of the init scrips on debian. Overall, the line will looks something like

`Cmnd_Alias WEBDAEMONS /etc/init.d/proftpd, /etc/init.d/mysql, /etc/init.d/samba`

Next, authorize the www-data user to run those commands as root without a password on any server where this `sudoers` file is installed. That should look like

`www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: WEBDAEMONS`

Finally, save the file and exit visudo. At this point, you should be able to log in as the `www-data` user and use sudo to run the commands you put in your command alias without needing to enter password. You could test this with something like the following:

`billy@example:~$ sudo -i -u www-data bash

[sudo] password for billy:

www-data@example:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd restart

Restarting proftpd

www-data@example:~$ exit`

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like proftpd then does not have the rights to create socket-files an so on.  

"notice: unable to bind to Unix domain socket at '/var/run/proftpd/test.sock': Permission denied"

Comment: My bad! I didn't start it as root. Many thanks.

Comment: Twmic You need an equals sign after Cmnd_Alias like `Cmnd_Alias ALIAS_NAME = [path]`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --chuid www-data
```

Full details are in `man start-stop-daemon(8)`.

[start-stop-daemon man page](http://man.he.net/man8/start-stop-daemon)

Note that in the case of ProFTPd, you should just be putting:

```
User www-data
```

In your `proftpd.conf` file.

[ProFTPd User directive docs](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_User.html)

For MySQL, put:

```
user = someusername
```

in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

[mysqld user option docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_user)

---

For the password bit, I assume you're trying to enter your `sudo` password?

That's never a good way to do it.

One better way is to add lines like this to `/etc/sudoers` via `visudo`:

```
MYDAEMONS = /home/user/bin/startproftpd, /home/user/bin/startmysql  
youruser ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: MYDAEMONS
```

But I think we're still missing something.  Why do you need this script?  Is it just to change the user the daemon runs as?

Answer (score 1):

If your daemon doesn't play nicely with start-stop-daemon, you can always use sudo -u www-data /path/to/command